# JPA2 Criteria API .as(String.class) casting to char(1) - How do I work around this?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, casting, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Using the criteria api, I have a query which does something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SourcePath> pathQuery = cb.createQuery(SourcePath.class);
Root<SourcePath> pathRoot = pathQuery.from(SourcePath.class);
pathQuery.where(cb.equal(cb.literal(0x00010002).as(String.class), (pathRoot.get(SourcePath_.path))));

TypedQuery<SourcePath> query = entityManager.createQuery(pathQuery);
query.getResultList();
```

The resulting sql query results something like:

```
select ...snip aliases... from SourcePath where cast(x'00010002', char(1)) = path;
```

(path would be some nasty old alias, but that's irrelevant).

This query is incorrect.  Particularly, the cast: `cast(x'00010002', char(1))` is not a cast to as string, as specified by `.as(String.class)`, instead it should be either `cast(x'00010002', char)`, or `cast(x'00010002', char(N)` where `N` is a suitably big enough number.

I've isolated the cause of this cast failure to the MySqlDialect provided by org.hibernate. Particularly:

```
public String getCastTypeName(int code) {
    if ( code==Types.INTEGER ) {
       return "signed";
    }
     else if ( code==Types.VARCHAR ) {
        return "char";
    }
    ...snip...
}
```

Which farther down the chain is interpreted as a `char`, which is registered by the dialog: `registerColumnType( Types.CHAR, "char(1)" );`.

Finally, to my question.  How can I work around this behaviour?  Do I report it as a bug to Hibernate?  Do I extend the Dialog and correct the returned type from getCastTypeName?  Is there an alternative to `.as` which will appropriately cast?  Or, should I use strings everywhere I'm currently using hex-values to avoid touching edge cases of hibernate's implementation?

Thanks
idb

Comment: Extending the dialect seems like it would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: or fix the dialect, raise a issue on hibernate JIRA and submit your fix.

Comment: Extend the dialect, or use Strings everywhere until the bug is fixed. Raise a JIRA.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should use a String literal like `cb.literal("\u0001\u0002")`. Reasons:

1. It's the same thing as `cb.literal(0x00010002).as(String.class)`, but less verbose.
2. Does not hit any "edge case"
3. It's clearer: does "0x00010002" be treated in Big Endian or LE? Which encoding should be used?
4. You can improve legibility using constants (e.g.: `cb.literal(ASCII_SOH + ASCII_STX)` where SOH="\u0001" and STX="\u0002").

EDIT: Adding a better description, since I didn't see the "Or, should I use strings everywhere I'm currently using hex-values"

Comment: I mentioned this in my question: "Or, should I use strings everywhere I'm currently using hex-values to avoid...".  It certainly is an option.

Comment: Sorry about that. I made my "opinion" more formal now